# WordPress different menus for top menu items

Tags: wordpress

How do I get different menus for different menu item ?

Example -
Top Menu - Toys | Cloth | Electric

Main Menu 1 (Toys Menu) - RC | Guns | Dolls | Etc

Main Menu 2 (Cloth Menu) - Denim | Dress | Shoes

Main Menu 3 (Electric Menu) - TV | DVD | Laptops

so i want do this is if i click toys from top menu show toys menu. if i click cloth from top menu show cloth menu.

I tried with conditional menu but no luck. please help with this thanks.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/conditional-menus/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to set any condition to show child menus of a parent. They need to be designed in that way. You can designed as a dropdown menu. WordPress already has facilities to create child menus under a parent menu item. You need to implement them properly in the front end.
You may see this [article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-dropdown-menu-in-wordpress-beginners-guide/)

Comment: Thanks for help bro. but i want place it two different places. is it possible place child menu different location. thanks again

Comment: Yes of course. why not? You can create menu as many as you want. Creating / registering a menu you should use register_nav_menu function as described 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menu/

Comment: thank you bro. any idea of place child menu in different location. example - main menu in top bar and its submenu not display hover always visible in other location.

Comment: In your template fields you will need to specify which menu you want using the wp_nav_menu() function after you've registered it. More info @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/